I'm getting "Sample rate must be 8k, 16k, 32k, or 48k" error in webRTC VAD project
I'm making a video translator tool which translates a youtube video when yt video link is given to them I'm downloading yt videos using yt-dlp, and using huggingface whisper:
            ydl_opts = {
                'format': 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best',
                'outtmpl': '%(id)s.%(ext)s',
                'noplaylist': True
            }
            with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                info_dict = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)
                video_file = f"{info_dict['id']}.mp4"

            temp_file_path = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.mp4')
            os.rename(video_file, temp_file_path)

            # Keeping track of video clip for the sake of audio tracking for STT
            video_clip = VideoFileClip(temp_file_path)
            audio_clip = video_clip.audio

The above step gets the audio from youtube video
And this is the remaining process, where I'm trying to get audio translation and fit it into video
# Create a temp audio file
            temp_audio_file = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.wav')
            audio_clip.write_audiofile(temp_audio_file)

            # Convert the audio file to mono
            mono_audio_file = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.wav')
            convert_to_mono(temp_audio_file, mono_audio_file)

            # Split the audio into segments using VAD
            segments, sample_rate = vad_split(mono_audio_file)

            translated_segments = []

            for segment in segments:
                temp_segment_path = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.wav')
                write_wave(temp_segment_path, segment, sample_rate)
                
                # Transcribe the audio using Whisper
                original_text = whisper(temp_segment_path)['text']
                print('Original Text:', original_text)

                # Translate the text
                translated_text = translator.translate(original_text, dest='es').text
                print('Translated Text:', translated_text)

                # Generate translated audio
                translated_audio_path = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.mp3')
                generate_translated_audio(translated_text, translated_audio_path)
                
                translated_segments.append(AudioSegment.from_mp3(translated_audio_path))
                
                os.remove(temp_segment_path)
                os.remove(translated_audio_path)

            # Concatenate all translated segments
            final_translated_audio = sum(translated_segments)

            # Save the final translated audio to a temporary file
            final_translated_audio_file = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.mp3')
            final_translated_audio.export(final_translated_audio_file, format='mp3')

            # Load the translated speech as an audio clip
            translated_audio_clip = AudioFileClip(final_translated_audio_file)

            # Replace the original audio with the translated audio
            final_video = video_clip.set_audio(translated_audio_clip)

            # Save the final video to a temporary file
            final_video_file = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.mp4')
            final_video.write_videofile(final_video_file, codec="libx264")

            # Clean up temporary files
            os.remove(temp_audio_file)
            os.remove(mono_audio_file)
            os.remove(final_translated_audio_file)
            video_clip.close()
            translated_audio_clip.close()

            return send_file(final_video_file, as_attachment=True, download_name=f"{info_dict['title']}_translated.mp4")

And the rtcvad processing methods which I've written are:
def convert_to_mono(input_path, output_path):
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(input_path)
    mono_audio = audio.set_channels(1)
    mono_audio.export(output_path, format="wav")

def read_wave(path):
    try:
        with wave.open(path, 'rb') as wf:
            num_channels = wf.getnchannels()
            assert num_channels == 1, "Audio file must be mono"
            sample_width = wf.getsampwidth()
            assert sample_width == 2, "Audio file must be 16-bit"
            sample_rate = wf.getframerate()
            assert sample_rate in (8000, 16000, 32000, 48000), "Sample rate must be 8k, 16k, 32k, or 48k"
            pcm_data = wf.readframes(wf.getnframes())
            return pcm_data, sample_rate
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in read_wave: {e}")
        raise

def write_wave(path, audio, sample_rate):
    try:
        with wave.open(path, 'wb') as wf:
            wf.setnchannels(1)
            wf.setsampwidth(2)
            wf.setframerate(sample_rate)
            wf.writeframes(audio)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in write_wave: {e}")
        raise

def vad_split(audio_path, aggressiveness=1):
    try:
        audio, sample_rate = read_wave(audio_path)
        vad = webrtcvad.Vad(aggressiveness)
        frames = np.frombuffer(audio, dtype=np.int16)
        frame_duration = 30  # ms
        frame_size = int(sample_rate * frame_duration / 1000)  # samples
        num_frames = len(frames) // frame_size

        segments = []
        segment = []

        for i in range(num_frames):
            frame = frames[i*frame_size:(i+1)*frame_size]
            is_speech = vad.is_speech(frame.tobytes(), sample_rate)
            if is_speech:
                segment.extend(frame)
            else:
                if segment:
                    segments.append(np.array(segment, dtype=np.int16).tobytes())
                    segment = []

        if segment:
            segments.append(np.array(segment, dtype=np.int16).tobytes())

        return segments, sample_rate

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in vad_split: {e}")
        raise

This is the error i got when i made a call to this route


I'm trying to split the audio into segments and then translate each segment and convert it into audio, then i want to join all segments and form one translated audio file which overlaps perfectly with the video (Background sound in video should exist)

Then fit that audio in videoclip and send the translated video as response


Here's the route I've written for that process:
@app.route('/post',methods =['POST'])

def process_video():
    data = request.get_json()
    if data and 'info' in data:
        url = data['info']
        print(url)
        try:
            # Download video using yt-dlp
            ydl_opts = {
                'format': 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best',
                'outtmpl': '%(id)s.%(ext)s',
                'noplaylist': True
            }
            with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                info_dict = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)
                video_file = f"{info_dict['id']}.mp4"

            temp_file_path = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.mp4')
            os.rename(video_file, temp_file_path)

            # Keeping track of video clip for the sake of audio tracking for STT
            video_clip = VideoFileClip(temp_file_path)
            audio_clip = video_clip.audio

            # Create a temp audio file
            temp_audio_file = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.wav')
            audio_clip.write_audiofile(temp_audio_file)

            # Convert the audio file to mono
            mono_audio_file = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.wav')
            convert_to_mono(temp_audio_file, mono_audio_file)

            # Split the audio into segments using VAD
            segments, sample_rate = vad_split(mono_audio_file)

            translated_segments = []

            for segment in segments:
                temp_segment_path = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.wav')
                write_wave(temp_segment_path, segment, sample_rate)
                
                # Transcribe the audio using Whisper
                original_text = whisper(temp_segment_path)['text']
                print('Original Text:', original_text)

                # Translate the text
                translated_text = translator.translate(original_text, dest='es').text
                print('Translated Text:', translated_text)

                # Generate translated audio
                translated_audio_path = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.mp3')
                generate_translated_audio(translated_text, translated_audio_path)
                
                translated_segments.append(AudioSegment.from_mp3(translated_audio_path))
                
                os.remove(temp_segment_path)
                os.remove(translated_audio_path)

            # Concatenate all translated segments
            final_translated_audio = sum(translated_segments)

            # Save the final translated audio to a temporary file
            final_translated_audio_file = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.mp3')
            final_translated_audio.export(final_translated_audio_file, format='mp3')

            # Load the translated speech as an audio clip
            translated_audio_clip = AudioFileClip(final_translated_audio_file)

            # Replace the original audio with the translated audio
            final_video = video_clip.set_audio(translated_audio_clip)

            # Save the final video to a temporary file
            final_video_file = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.mp4')
            final_video.write_videofile(final_video_file, codec="libx264")

            # Clean up temporary files
            os.remove(temp_audio_file)
            os.remove(mono_audio_file)
            os.remove(final_translated_audio_file)
            video_clip.close()
            translated_audio_clip.close()

            return send_file(final_video_file, as_attachment=True, download_name=f"{info_dict['title']}_translated.mp4")

        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({"error": f'{str(e)} at line {e.__traceback__.tb_lineno}'}), 400

    return jsonify({"error": "No data received"}), 400

